# How to add variables sequentially in ordinal package in R

Tags: r, regression, ordinal-data

I am trying to fit an ordinal regression model using the `logit` link function in R using `ordinal` package; the response variables have five levels.

The number of explanatory variables is much larger than the number of samples ($p \gg n$)

Could any one help me with the following problem:

1. Start with a model that contains only the intercept.
2. For the current model, explore the improvement in fit by adding additional variables.
3. Add the baseline for the variables that performed the best (using AIC, deviance, etc.)
4. Go back to step 2 until the maximal number of variables in the model is reached.

Unfortunately, `glmnet`, cannot handle ordinal regression otherwise it would have been great. Is there a way of reducing the ordinal regression problem to multinomial regression using indicator variables? This would be of great benefit as I could use `glmnet` for variable selection.

This is sample data (in my case $n \sim 100$, and $p \sim 10000$):

```
structure(list(resp = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"b"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), x1 = 1:5, x2 = c(0.1, 
0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5), x3 = c(0.01, 0.04, 0.09, 0.16, 0.25), x4 = c(1, 
4, 9, 16, 25), x5 = c(0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005), x6 = c(-5, 
-4, -3, -2, -1), x7 = c(-0.5, -0.4, -0.3, -0.2, -0.1), x8 = c(0.25, 
0.16, 0.09, 0.04, 0.01), x9 = c(25, 16, 9, 4, 1), x10 = c(0.0316227766016838, 
0.0447213595499958, 0.0547722557505166, 0.0632455532033676, 0.0707106781186548
)), .Names = c("resp", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7", 
"x8", "x9", "x10"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: how about `stepAIC()` in package MASS?

Comment: @chase thanks. I had thought about `polr`, but I wanted to use `clm` and polr is slow with my data size (and so is `clm`)

Comment: This seems like two questions: One about how to do something in R (and not something that I'd recommend doing) and the other about how to express ordinal logistic as multinomial. The first is off topic here, so I am voting to close. But the second seems like a statistics problem. So, if you edit your question, maybe it can be re-opened.